# Adding a non-null ForeignKey field in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I want to add a new Model which consists of a refernce to django users model.
The existing model is signed in users table provided by django and new model has a foriegn key to user.
What is the command to add all existing users in the django users table to this new model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [Migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/). Migrations come in two flavors: schema and data.

You'll need to issue the `makemigrations` command to alter your schema:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then you can either add a data migration using:

```
$ python manage.py makemigration --empty [appname]
```

and add the necessary Python code to populate your users, or you can alter the automatically generated migration to add the population step after the schema is altered.

If you're using a version of Django prior to 1.7, you'll need to use [South](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to create your migrations.